# PDF appears very dark when viewed in DocView on MacOS

Tags: osx, pdf, docview, emacs-mac-port

When I view PDFs in Emacs using DocView, they appear much darker than they should:

[image: Emacs and Preview displaying the same PDF, where the PDF appears much darker in Emacs]

I am not sure why this happens -- I haven't changed any settings related to DocView or enabled any minor modes that would cause this. Disabling my current emacs config (by moving .emacs.d) does not resolve this. I am using the mituharu emacs-mac port from [this](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport) Homebrew formula, but the issue also exists with the build from https://emacsformacosx.com. My .emacs.d is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/AjayMT/.emacs.d).

I've tried using `doc-view-clear-cache` and `revert-buffer`, but neither of these help.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? How would I go about resolving this?

UPDATE:
This seems to be caused by GhostScript. DocView runs the following command to convert each page of a PDF into a PNG:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dBATCH -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dQUIET -r100 -sOutputFile=out.png in.pdf
```

Running this command produces dark gray images like the one I see in Emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by installing mupdf (`brew install mupdf`), which caused DocView to use `mudraw` as the PDF->PNG conversion backend instead of Ghostscript. Running `doc-view-clear-cache` after installing mupdf fixed the issue.